# No suitable method found for into(BitmapDrawable)

Tags: android

[image]

```
BitmapDrawable imageViewTarget = new BitmapDrawable(String.valueOf(gif));
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.anim_logo).into(imageViewTarget);
```

Comment: imageViewTarget dosent work

Comment: The target must be an ImageView or a subclass of ImageView. You are using a drawable as the target. Thats why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

replace your code like this

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.anim_logo).into(gif);
```

instead of

```
  Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.anim_logo).into(imageViewTarget);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are going to wrong flow of glide implimentation. please read documentation

your put in code  Glide.with(your_base_activity).load(R.drawable.anim_logo).into(gif);